# self.view.stuff doesn't work inside method

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I'm having some trouble trying to make a simple view background within a method like:

```
self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
```

It works on the "- (void)viewDidLoad" thing, but not on mine.
Heres the .m:

```
#import "DetailView.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"

@interface DetailView ()
@end

@implementation DetailView
static DetailView *_sharedInstance;
MainViewController *mainView;

+ (DetailView *) sharedInstance
{
    if (!_sharedInstance)
    {
    _sharedInstance = [[DetailView alloc] init];
    }

    return _sharedInstance;
}
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    mainView = [MainViewController sharedInstance];
    self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];   //Works here! D:
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)createOption:(CGRect)pos Valor1:(NSString *)valor1 Valor2:(NSString *)valor2{
    self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];   //Doesn't work here :(
}

@end
```

and here's my .h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DetailView : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *controlVar;
+ (DetailView *) sharedInstance;

-(void)createOption:(CGRect)pos Valor1:(NSString *)valor1 Valor2:(NSString *)valor2;
@end
```

Edit:
Here's where I'm calling the 'createOption' (on viewDidLoad of the another class):

```
DetailView *detailView = [DetailView sharedInstance];
[detailView createOption:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50) Valor1:@"Teste1" Valor2:@"Teste2"];
```

What am i missing here and how can i fix it?

Comment: What calls the `createOption:Valor1:Valor2:]` method? And when?

Comment: How do you know its not calling? did you tried it with different background color? right now both are same.
And who is calling createOption:Valor1 ?

Comment: Oh no no, i'm caling it from another class. Already put a "NSlog" inside it to test.

Comment: @markus I think you are looking for `Delegate - Protocol`.

Comment: @markus Update your question to show how you create your `DetailView` and call the `createOption:Valor1:Valor2:` method.

Comment: I guess you are trying to create a common function to be used in `multiple UIViewControllers` ?

Comment: Exactly. I'm telling one view to change another view's back color.

Comment: Creating an instance does not mean that the view is loaded. Maybe you need to call `[detailView view]` so it implicitly call the method `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you don't instantiate DetailView sharedInstance with the instance you have on the screen. Look at this code:

In ViewController.m

```
static ViewController *sharedInstance = nil;
+(void)setSharedInstance:(ViewController *)someInstance
{
    sharedInstance = (ViewController *)someInstance;
}
+(ViewController *)sharedInstance
{
    return sharedInstance;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [ViewController setSharedInstance:self];
}
```

In second ViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
ViewController *shared = [ViewController sharedInstance];
```

shared.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; //now is working
    }

Don't forget to put the class methods in .h file to be public and import first ViewController in second ViewController.

Comment: Yeah, obviously. But the main idea is to check out if he instantiate the ViewController with the sharedInstance when he present it in his interface. If he present it with an automat segue then the sharedInstance is not called.

Comment: Didn't work. Now not even the function calling works.

Answer (score 0):

As per discussion, you are trying to create a common function that can be easily used in different `UIViewControllers`. It can be easily achieved by creating a UIViewController category class, and adding an extra functionality. See below

**`UIViewController+Additions.h`**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIViewController (Additions)
-(void)createOption:(CGRect)pos Valor1:(NSString *)valor1 Valor2:(NSString *)valor2;
@end
```

**`UIViewController+Additions.m`**

```
#import "UIViewController+Additions.h"

@implementation UIViewController (Additions)
-(void)createOption:(CGRect)pos Valor1:(NSString *)valor1 Valor2:(NSString *)valor2{

    self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
}
@end
```

Now add `#import "UIViewController+Additions.h"` in your other class, and in `viewDidLoad` just call

```
[self createOption:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50) Valor1:@"Teste1" Valor2:@"Teste2"];
```

But question is why your code doesn't work, because of wrong reference you have. Though the way I have described is correct way to achieve this kind of implementations. Another way is create normal `UIViewController` class add properties, and change the UIViewController class of second viewcontroller to BaseViewController.

I hope it helps.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt work there because the method you wrote the change in background i.e - createOption.
Call the method in viewDidLoad or any IBaction that you plan to add.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    mainView = [MainViewController sharedInstance];

    [self createOption:(CGRect)pos Valor1:yourParameter1 Valor2:yourParameter2]; // now this will work too :D
 }
```

the reason it wasnt working is because u wrote the method but u wer'nt calling the method

Hope it helps

Comment: My whole point is to call that function outside the main class

Comment: then call the method in another method that is being called in the main class or in an ibaction method or a method that gets fired when u want it to execute.